# Select specific child of the current element using THIS

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, dom-events

I would like to know how can I select `<span ="data">` from the following.

```
<div class="feeds" onmouseover="...">
    <div id="someDiv"></div>
    <div class="moredivs"></div>
    <span ="data">data in here...</span>
</div>
```

I would like to use something like: `onmouseover="select(this)"` and then be able to access that span based on that event, because I have may `<div class="feeds">` elements.

Even a JQuery suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML you have provided is invalid. When defining attributes, you have to give them a name. Let's assume you have this:

```
 <span class="data">data in here...</span>
```

With jQuery, you can simply do this without an inline event handler. In your `$(document).ready()` you could put:

```
$('.feeds').mouseover(function () {
    var $span=$('span.data', this);
});
```

`$span` will hold access to your `span` (in a jQuery collection).

[jsFiddle Demo - jQuery version](http://jsfiddle.net/6Gxuk/1/)

---

If you need a Javascript only solution (with your inline event handler: `onmouseover="select(this)"`), you would go with something like this:

```
function select(me) {
    var span=me.getElementsByClassName('data')[0];
}
```

`getElementsByClassName()` is only available on modern browsers, but you can use a [fallback](http://robertnyman.com/2005/11/07/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname/) as well for ancient IEs.

[jsFiddle Demo - Plain Javascript / Inline handler](http://jsfiddle.net/6Gxuk/)

---

**Note:** If you have more than one `.feeds`, please consider using a class instead of an id for `someDiv`, because an id can only appear once in a HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/4NAJ9/1/

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.feeds').hover(function(){
        var data_span = $(this).find('.data');
        alert(data_span.html());
    }, function(){
        // If you wanted something to happen 'onmouseout', put it here
    });
});
</script>

<div class="feeds">
    <div id="someDiv"></div>
    <div class="moredivs"></div>
    <span class="data">data in here...</span>
</div>
```

If you're willing to use jQuery, then you really don't want to be adding an inline `onclick` event to each `.feeds` element.

It's better to keep your Javascript separate from your HTML - jQuery allows you to do this easily.

Comment: Thank you guys. It worked. Just one last thing. How do I flag this post as answered? Is it possible/necessary? Im new in SO.

Comment: @Sthe Just click the tickmark on the left of the question you like most.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('.feeds').mouseover(function() {
  $('span',this).html();
});
```